# Understanding Vuex getters and mutations

Tags: javascript, vuex

Let's say I have a vuex store like this...

```
state: {
  docs: null, 
  adds: [],
  deletes: [],
},
actions: {
  // initialize docs to an array of objects
  init (context, payload) {
  }
}
getters: {
  // get the docs plus the adds, minus the deletes
  docs (state) {
  }
},
mutations: {
  // add a doc, keeping track that it was added
  addDoc (state, payload) {
  }
  // remove a doc, keeping track that it was deleted
  removeDoc (state, payload) {
  }
}
```

I think I have two choices to implement: either mutate the docs array on the setters, or compute the *effective value* of the array on the getter.  Is one of these ideas much worse than the other either in terms of reactivity or performance?

In other words:

```
// choice 1: really mutate the docs
addDoc (state, payload) {
  state.adds = [...state.adds, ...payload]
  state.docs = _.without([...state.docs, ...payload], state.deletes)
}

// choice 2: mutate the docs in effect, via the getter
addDoc (state, payload) {
  state.adds = [...state.adds, ...payload]
}

// choice 2, in getter
docs(state) {
  return _.without([...state.docs, ...payload], state.deletes)
}
```

Assuming the mutation is made infrequently, and the getter is called frequently, am I paying a computational penalty with choice 2?  Or, since the getter results are cached (I think?) are the two approaches really about the same? Is it a coin toss about which way to go, or is there a principal I can use to decide?  -- Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm yes, getters are cached. So in this case just flip a coin I guess. Personally, I prefer to make compute on getters.

Comment: Thanks.  That seems smart, too, because it will then be zero cost to get the docs separate from the adds/deletes.  I'll use this answer.